# Open pdf file in browser with url generated in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm working with .net 4.0 in asp.net.

I have folder on web server having some pdf file, I display its (File Name) Name  in gridview then i want to do "when i click on Item in grid view then it open that pdf file and generate url with file in browser."

I'm using Following Code

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).Parent.Parent;
LinkButton hk = (LinkButton)gvFiles.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("lnkbtnTitleView");
string s = Server.MapPath("~/AppName/App_" + dtFiles.Rows[0]["ENewsLetterID"].ToString() + "_1.PDF");
hk.Attributes.Add("onclick","window.open('"+s+"')");
```

Answer (score 1):

Add ashx handler to your website, that will send pdf as content back to client. Add links to gridview, that will reference to this handler.

Answer (score 0):

If the PDF file already exists simply put direct link:

```
string s = string.Format("/AppName/App_{0}_1.PDF", dtFiles.Rows[0]["ENewsLetterID"]);
```

And add window name `_blank`:

```
hk.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("window.open('{0}', '_blank');", s));
```

Otherwise please give more details: how the PDF should be generated?

Comment: its Working but new browser Window is open and close automatically .open the pdf file not in  the browser window but directly in Acrobat reader.

Comment: @sur that's up to the browser... if proper plugin/extension is installed, the PDF will be displayed directly inside the new browser window. To force file download see gor answer, you'll have to add proper header `Content-type: application/pdf`, `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=[name here]` and use something like `Response.WriteFile`

Comment: when i write it it start download file. i want to only open the file in new browser window with url on that.